# CSS3 Animations Border Expanding Outwards from Center

Tags: css, animation, width, border, reverse

[Image Example for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Auq.jpg)

Making a website and really getting into CSS3 animations for the first time. Ideally, I want those two gray borders animating outwards from the logo in the center. I currently have them animating but they only animate left to right. They are done by having a div on both sides with a border-bottom. Because of this, I thought animating the div's width from 0 to 100 was the best approach. It's working great... just not in the right direction lol.

Note: the CSS is in stylus so there isn't normal syntax.

**Animation Keyframes:**

```
@keyframes widthExpand {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }

  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

**Assigning Class:**

```
.fadewidth
  animation-name widthExpand, fadeIn
  animation-duration 2000ms, 2000ms
  transition-timing-function ease-in
  animation-direction normal
```

I've tried different animation directions and having the 0% start at width 100% then reversing it, hoping it would fix it. Always animates left to right no matter what I do.

It's also position horizontally centered with flexbox. Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="centernav" class="">
    <div class="left-links">

        <div class="top-links fadewidth">
        </div>

        <div class="bottom-links">
        </div>

    </div>

    <img src="assets/images/cv-logo-yellow-nodate.svg" id="cvlogo-main" class="fadeindown">

    <div class="right-links">

        <div class="top-links fadewidth">
        </div>

        <div class="bottom-links">
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS: Stylus**

```
.left-links,
.right-links
    width 30%

.top-links
    border-bottom 1px solid #fafafa

#centernav
    display flex
    align-items center
    justify-content center
    flex-direction row
    height 85%
    color nardo

    & h1
        font-family heading
        color gold
        font-size 6.5rem
        font-weight 100
        margin-bottom -22px

    & img
        margin 0 50px
```

I feel like this is probably something really simple I'm missing in maybe the keyframe declaration. Thanks for your help!

Comment: To elaborate... https://jsfiddle.net/k8s1h32o/
I would need this to animate right to left.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Since they are positioned center, the animation will force outwards if you give them an absolute position. I gave the parent div a relative position and the inner divs an absolute position.

**Note**: you have to give it an absolute position within the keyframe declaration. I tried applying an absolute position in the CSS for the class but it created a weird effect once the animation sequence was done.

I simply did the following:

```
@keyframes widthExpand {
  from {
    width: 0%;
    position: absolute;
  }

  to {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```